# Express 4.13 blank json request with body-parser

Tags: jquery, ajax, node.js, express, body-parser

I have an express server using the following params and routes

```
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var router = express.Router();
var app = express();
app.use(router);
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded());
var jsonParser = bodyParser.json({ type: 'application/json'});

router.post('/login', jsonParser, function(req, res) {
    console.log('request body : ' + req.body);
});
```

and my ajax callback is as follows

```
    var user = {
        username: $("#_username").val(),
        password: $("#_password").val()
    }
    var jsonText = JSON.stringify(user);
    console.log(jsonText);
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "http://localhost:3002/login",
        async: true,
        dataType: 'json',
        data: jsonText,
        cache: false,
        success: function(data, textStatus, xhr) {
        },
        error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        }
    });
```

I don't understand why i'm getting nothing but an empty array in the body type and have followed the body-parser example on npm almost to the letter.

Any idea why it's doing this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't created an instance of the `application/json` parser, per [the docs:](https://www.npmjs.com/package/body-parser)

```
var express = require('express')
var bodyParser = require('body-parser')

var app = express()

// create application/json parser 
var jsonParser = bodyParser.json()

// create application/x-www-form-urlencoded parser 
var urlencodedParser = bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false })
```

This line of code changes the accepted "types" the json parser is willing to accept - you're changing the settings (if you've got some custom json objects):

```
var jsonParser = bodyParser.json({ type: 'application/json'});
```

It would also be good to validate that your post request is firing at all...

```
router.post('/login', jsonParser, function(req, res) {
    console.log("posted!");
}
```

Comment: Your answer helped me find the issue, the server wasnt the problem, the ajax request was, the contentType wasn't set  to json, therefore it was looking for xml (cause its the standard)